# Plugin nicescroll erro no Chorme

Tags: jquery

estou tendo problemas com o plugin `nicescroll` do `JQuery` no `Chrome`

Estou fazendo assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_scripts/_funcoes/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_scripts/_funcoes/_js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_scripts/_funcoes/_js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_scripts/_funcoes/_js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_scripts/_funcoes/_js/scrowSuave.js"></script>
```

scrowSuave.js

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("html").niceScroll();
  });
});
```

No Internet Explorer a barra de rolagem aparece e tudo funciona bem.
Mas no Chorme, a barra some e parece que tudo que esta abaixo da chamada trava.

Coloquei neste endereço para verem.

http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/cintialima.com.br/

Esse erro só ocorre no `Chorme` e `Firefox`. `Edge` e `IE` não apresenta erro.

NÃO dá erro no console

Outra observação é que, ao ver o código fonte da página, a página toda foi gerada até o `/html`, porém a exibição dela fica travada na metade e a barra de rolagem já não existe! A barra de rolagem é desabilitada!

Grato a quem puder ajudar.

Carlos Rocha

Comment: Coloca no tópico a mensagem de erro que está dando no `localhost`.